# get coordinates Latlng for google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have this code:

```js
function initialize() {

   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0.0, 0.0);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom:7,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
          var  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("cluster_map"), myOptions);
    refreshMap();
}





function refreshMap() {
    if (markerClusterer) {
        markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    }
    $.getJSON(__cfg('json_data_url'), function(data) {
        if (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data['Properties']['Count']; i ++ ) {
                updateClusterMarker(data['Properties'][i]['Property'].latitude, data['Properties'][i]['Property'].longitude, data['Properties'][i]['Property'].id, i, 'Property');
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < data['Requests']['Count']; i ++ ) {
                updateClusterMarker(data['Requests'][i]['Request'].latitude, data['Requests'][i]['Request'].longitude, data['Requests'][i]['Request'].id, i, 'Request');
            }
            var zoom = null;
            var size = null;
            var style = null;
            markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
                maxZoom: zoom,
                gridSize: size,
                styles: styles[style]
   });
        }
    });
}
function updateClusterMarker(lat, lang, id, count, type) {
 var imageUrl = __cfg('path_relative') + 'img/R.png';
    if (type == 'Property') {
        var imageUrl = __cfg('path_relative') + 'img/P.png';
    }
    var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl, new google.maps.Size(32, 32));
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang);
    eval('var marker' + count + ' = new google.maps.Marker({position: latLng,draggable: false,icon: markerImage});');
    eval('marker' + count + '.count=1');
    markers.push(eval('marker' + count));
 var embed_url = __cfg('path_relative') + 'requests/get_info/' + id;
    if (type == 'Property') {
        var embed_url = __cfg('path_relative') + 'properties/get_info/' + id;
    }
    var contentString = '<iframe src="' + embed_url + '" width="279" height="120" frameborder = "0" scrolling="no">Loading...</iframe>';
    eval('var infowindow' + count + ' = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString,  maxWidth: 300});');
    var infowindow_obj = eval('infowindow' + count);
    var marker_obj = eval('marker' + count);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker_obj, 'click', function() {
        infowindow_obj.open(map, marker_obj);
    });
}
```

It works fine as it is but when i'm trying to center the map same position as the marker it won't work. i tried this code:

```js
   var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang);
```

Does anyone knows how to center the map same position as the marker?
any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Which marker are you trying to center on?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue you are trying to address.

Comment: this marker:                                                                                                              var markerImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(imageUrl, new google.maps.Size(32, 32));  i'm trying to get same lat and lng as marker  and center the map to them

Comment: i see that the marker gets its lat and lng with this:  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang); but for the center it's not working

Comment: Where is that in the posted code? Are you calling `map.setCenter(latLng)` somewhere? (BTW is your longitude really named `lang`?).

Comment: FYI - `MarkerImage` was deprecated a long time ago in favor of the `Icon` anonymous object.

Comment: the script is made by someone from India, and a friend asked me to check it out to see if i can center the map in the same place as the marker is. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the marker position with its `.getPosition()` method (it returns a `LatLng` class object). So, you could use something like `map.panTo(marker.getPosition());`

Example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/khL6pz04/)):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(22.669, 77.709),
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(22.669, 77.709),
        map: map
    });

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
    });
};
```

Comment: i use this code to get the position for some properties and i can't put default values for lat and lng , it has to get them as the marker does and i don't know how, i tried var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang); but return nothing

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it:

```js
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lang);
 
    var myOptions = {
 minZoom:4,
        zoom: 19,
        center: latLng,
        zoomControl: true,
        draggable: true,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('cluster_map'), myOptions);

        
    refreshMap();
}
```